# Automatic type conversion of generic for dictionary of functions

Tags: typescript, generics, polymorphism, typescript-generics

Say I have a dictionary of functions like so:

```
interface Base {
  name: string;
}

interface Foo extends Base {
  name: 'FOO',
  propA: string
}

interface Bar extends Base {
  name: 'BAR'
  propB: number
}

const callers: { [key: string]: <T extends Base>(x: T) => T } = {
  'FOO': (x: Foo) => x,
  'BAR': (x: Bar) => x
}

const call = <T extends Base>(x: T): T => {
  return callers[x.name](x)
}
```

how can I tell typescript that if this dictionary is called with the right key, we can assume that the passed in parameter is of the right type?

([tsplayground with the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EGiSyIoBiA9v2QQAHpBAATDGkw4CREuSoByXgHk1ygDSt2%20TtHhIZUYWIiTp6LMjyFiZSsmWoAggCVlu-AQT8QNMgIcAA2IdAYVNjIANoA1hAAnlQ0dCD0ALpUADwAKmbiUjJYAHwAFCJUuQCUyAC8Jcj5LPW28s7qmlQVVAL8tQ3IIjr2Lh7K3ZUmA40i3r7%20gcFhrXkFFkXWEOVTNVX1jXZEUBBgAK5QIEGh4VAYMSIAdIoQGRXVrEA))

Comment: This is the issue described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The relevant refactoring looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1P5AW).  If that fully addresses your question I could write up an answer; otherwise, let me know what is missing.  (Possibly relevant: do you intend for `Foo` and `Bar` to be nothing but a `name` property? Or are you leaving out other properties for brevity?)

Comment: I'm leaving out other properties for brevity, updated the question to better reflect this.

Comment: So then [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJyoVm) is the relevant refactoring. Let me know if I should write up an answer or if I'm missing something about your question.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help! Feel free to add this as the answer and I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written your `callers` typing is not strictly correct.  The type `<T extends Base>(x: T) => T` means that the *caller* gets to choose `T`.  According to that, `callers.FOO` would have to accept a `Bar` if the caller wanted.  That's not what `callers` does, so the compiler complains.

You could start to fix it by defining a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Either` of all your explicitly handled subtypes of `Base`:

```
type Either = Foo | Bar
```

And then saying that `callers` has a type that depends on it (say as a [mapped type over `Either` with remapped keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
const callers: { [T in Either as T["name"]]: (x: T) => T } = {
  'FOO': (x: Foo) => x,
  'BAR': (x: Bar) => x
} // okay!
```

Now there's no error there, but then this is a problem:

```
const call = <T extends Base>(x: T): T => {
  return callers[x.name](x); // error! 
  // can't index into callers with an arbitrary string
}
```

Oh, right, `call()` doesn't handle *arbitrary* subtypes of `Base`, it only handles `Either`.  Let's fix that by changing the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) from `Base` to `Either`.  Uh oh:

```
const call = <T extends Either>(x: T): T => {
  return callers[x.name](x) // error!
  // Either is not assignable to Foo & Bar
}
```

And now we're stuck.  The compiler doesn't realize that the type of `callers[x.name]` is *correlated* with the type of `x` in the right way.  Conceptually it seems like the compiler should just "see" that it works for "each" possible narrowing of `x` from `Either`.  If `x` is a `Foo` it works. If `x` is a `Bar` it works.  So it should work.

But that's not how the compiler looks at it.  It examines the code once total, not for each narrowing.  So `x` is `Foo | Bar`, and thus `callers[x.name]` is some function which *might* take a `Foo` or it *might* take a `Bar` but the compiler doesn't know which.  And the only safe input for such a function in general is something that's *both* a `Foo` *and* a `Bar`... that's a `Foo & Bar`.  But `x` is a `Foo | Bar` not a `Foo & Bar`.  In fact there are no possible values of type `Foo & Bar` because the `name` property would have to be both `"FOO"` and `"BAR"` and there are no strings of that type.  So the compiler complains and gives up.

---

This problem, whereby the compiler loses track of the correlation in types between two values, especially of a function type and it input type, is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  It's also the subject of [a recent twitter thread by @RyanCavanaugh](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414378383925250).

You can just throw a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at it and move on with your life:

```
const call = <T extends Either>(x: T): T => {
  return (callers[x.name] as <T extends Either>(x: T) => T)(x) // okay
}
```

But this is just telling the compiler to ignore the issue.  So you need to be careful not to do the wrong thing, because the compiler won't catch it.

```
const call = <T extends Either>(x: T): T => {
  return (callers.FOO as <T extends Either>(x: T) => T)(x) // still okay?!
  //   ------> ^^^^
}
```

---

For a long time that was the best one could do, or at least I thought so.  But then [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) made some fixes to allow a refactored version of the above to work.  The idea is to explicitly represent your operations in terms of a *distributive object type*, where you [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) keys of some mapping type and immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it.  This allows you to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions where all types are computed in terms of the generic key type `K` of this mapping type.  You can read ms/TS#47109 for more info, but here's the relevant refactoring of your above types:

```
interface Mapping {
  FOO: {
    propA: string;
  },
  BAR: {
    propB: number;
  }
}

type Mapped<K extends keyof Mapping = keyof Mapping> =
  { [P in K]: { name: P } & Mapping[P] }[K];

type Foo = Mapped<"FOO">
type Bar = Mapped<"BAR">
```

Your `Foo` and `Bar` types are subsumed into `Mapped<K>`.  The type `Mapped<"FOO">` is equivalent to `Foo`, and `Mapped<"BAR">` is equivalent to `Bar`.  And the type `Mapped` by itself is equivalent to `Either`.

Then `callers` should be annotated as being of a mapped type over the same keys:

```
const callers: { [K in keyof Mapping]: (x: Mapped<K>) => Mapped<K> } = {
  'FOO': (x: Foo) => x,
  'BAR': (x: Bar) => x
}
```

And finally, `call()` is generic over the same key, and the compiler is happy:

```
const call = <K extends keyof Mapping>(x: Mapped<K>): Mapped<K> => {
  return callers[x.name](x); // okay
}
```

And it will even complain if you do something wrong:

```
const call = <K extends keyof Mapping>(x: Mapped<K>): Mapped<K> => {
  return callers.FOO(x) // error!
}
```

And it works well from the caller's side, too:

```
call({ name: "FOO", propA: "hello" }); // okay
call({ name: "FOO", propB: 123 }); // error
call({ name: "BAR", propB: 123 }); // okay
```

So there you go.  It is possible to rewrite your code in such a way that the compiler accepts what you're doing as a single generic operation instead of as a collection of operations whose correlations it cannot track.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIDyATgJYDmeRJJdwALhDQGaVIAhEFGQFirEmQgAuJFA71gDANwtWAXyJq2nbn0RIAYgHtjSCAA8uwACZRBw0dtZTZAckNUqbgDTOSMDTGMACCsvKKDM6ahM7sXLz8QjTmVhC29kIizOISrkhuAiEASm7+SIHBArLAAK5gAEbc0Vq5SPDGwPLtmBjcULK4SADaANYQAJ7hCuwMALqyADwAKqnWdg4iAHwAFBayywCUSAC8W0ir6qc5EiQeXm6ye7ImxsdnSBZ+bXdFpU-7Bw0d7nCwtWJtDpdDg9DAYa4rNbpDZZCC7QFHA6nc5iW5IGgQDi1GjAWF9GhQYYWAB0Ujme0O4JIMTUUgoBgAyhw6HCAHLBJxteJ6JKOG63fIRWaqNosoW6RIGV5IjKbQV4-L3bzfPGVULTSLguIK-TIZIqlFi3ES8AyAp-Mo-CpBGDVUj1Jo0I1tDgTGDIACidA4AAtuNdlQAfIHOKHddBw-qDEardhIIOh8PCC7DABEUlzcwWSGeFxBFyQVxO4okWseJcBr3LX3KhRK9dLyWbTNYcZhphgUAAwr0EatLOtMo50QdDliPtaJASiSSyf0qbTbfSLIdlEgAPT78w0II0ACESHKh56wDcMPYNksSHiZgT5PsAHdgyGkCBSSAaAaYMaAAiY5BmJQexIPsyTHC17AzMMaBnMt5xxcpl2JUk33XGk6QZA8j24U8zyvI9EPDOh7GAYwYWEKBGFABo+iQDgzGVAAyGNZVaCQYLfEIoBEGgYWrREJ2RBDv24FDMQrBcMMJLCSxwikNzpX97HEtJVQo5DSyObEywI69jFGEAJm9PjOnjXpBOEjghBsOCJN06T9IxOd5PQp1MNXHZVKgak-k0pBtMndN3Nk8sjhMo8zIsqzK140hbXZZBiggfQ2JSMRjQSU0kAAWRAGAYFmGtWE8KhBnKAIXTCcDIhlPF1B1W4-lqp16qqGoPW4FrbhiCQ5QkX1-WK0r-RsRYAGl4KQcYJmMHhJrKirqyWla1vKpRzhOcohmGAAFZ9SVm4shnyU6ri4kr1qUE65krYYLplZxxuQZVq3u6bFlzarcy2D6-TNADrl+iAZtzP4gZS6CbJhQLk1es7FsmbbftmYtS0hmbZq2cs8bm84q0qu5qo7RtTGbdrawdAFZC7IywR4iFrOhWCxPm1yNi21asb23GpqhkmvOJgmjMXVg-Ow3pcM3SBt0ZNnY0RsknIRHmdL5jGBam2YUIlwnZGNqXFJXOXEwpalqri48SO9WNeh2K7bVkAGvFzHxnWCRrczDOFjFzStd0IpAEssyEXbdyAPcBn29TdABGAAmABmUO92vYjjC9aO4Vd1K46QGGSm933XVkNPM-UMPTPMqO1DldQgA)